# Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '[', expecting ')', possibly PHP version issue

Tags: php, api, object, instagram

My code is giving an error. I know now it has to do with the php version. But to what should i change my code for it to work correctly?

```
$json = file_get_contents(
'https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/'. $user_id .'/media/recent/?client_id=' . $client_id . '&count=' . $count);

$decode = json_decode($json, true);
$output = '';

$func = function($post['tags']){ 
    $i=0; 
    while(!empty($post['tags'])){ 
        return $post['tags'][$i]." ";
        $i++;
    }
};

foreach ($decode['data'] as $post) {
    $output .= $modx->getChunk($tpl,
        array(
            'link'      => $post['link']
            ,'image'     => $post['images']['standard_resolution']['url']
            ,'likes'     => $post['likes']['count']
            ,'hashtags'  => $func
        )
    );
}

return $output;
```

Thanks

Comment: I've never seen an "arse" error before :')

Comment: I have seen several arses @JamieSterling!

Comment: "arse error" is British.  American is "ass fault".

Comment: most likely the php version

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP Parse/Syntax Errors; and How to solve them?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18050071/php-parse-syntax-errors-and-how-to-solve-them)

Comment: @JayBlanchard I have not seen you commenting on the recent mysql_ questions. Where have you been?

Comment: It has been nuts around here @JamieSterling. Big project + some other things have limited my time on SO. How have you been?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is that you pass `$post['tags']` to the function declaration. You can change

```
$func = function($post['tags'])
...
```

to

```
$func = function($tags) {
    $i=0; 
    while(!empty($tags)){ 
        return $tags[$i]." ";
        $i++;
    }
}
```

and than call it as

```
$func($post['tags'])
```